# How can I properly Query data from a django model without

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, payment

im trying to create a simple django app for buying and selling shares but im having trouble querying my data properly specifically the amount of available shares.
These are my models:

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import CustomUser

class Share(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity_available = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    share = models.ForeignKey(Share, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_purchase = models.BooleanField()
```

then these are my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Share, Transaction
from .forms import BuyShareForm, SellShareForm

def buy_share(request):
    share = Share.objects.filter(quantity_available__gt=100)
    form = BuyShareForm(request.POST or None)
            
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
        
        if quantity <= share.quantity_available:
            transaction = Transaction(user=request.user, share=share, quantity=quantity,
                                      total_price=quantity * share.price, is_purchase=True)
            transaction.save()
            share.quantity_available -= quantity
            share.save()
            return redirect('shares:buy-success')
        else:
            form.add_error('quantity', 'Insufficient shares available')
            
    context = {
        'share': share,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'shares/buy_share.html', context)

def sell_share(request):
    share = Share.objects.all()
    form = SellShareForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
        
        transaction = Transaction(user=request.user, share=share, quantity=quantity,
                                  total_price=quantity * share.price, is_purchase=False)
        transaction.save()
        share.quantity_available += quantity
        share.save()
        return redirect('shares:sell_success')

    return render(request, 'shares:sell_share.html', {'form': form})
```

when i try to get the available shares using this "share = Share.objects.filter(quantity_available__gt=100)" is just get an error:

AttributeError at /shares/buy_share/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'quantity_available'

yet i had created a share called investment shares with a quantity of 100,000
i don't know if i was clear enough guys,
im still learning this stuff
hope someone helps

so guys i just wanted users to be able to buy and sell shares i hadn't implemented the payments processing yet. if anyone has other approaches to my problem im open for ideas im also planning on using the mobile money api for processing payments

Comment: `share` is not a *single* `Share`, it is a `QuerySet`, so a *collection* of shares, so `share.quantity_available` makes not much sense.

Comment: Either you replace .filter with .get to return only one object (which is not really advisable if you are not always sure about the amount of objects that will be returned), or run it through a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you provided, the "share" variable is of type django.db.models.QuerySet and it does not have the attribute quantity_available. Therefore, you need to use .first() or .last() to get a single object from your queryset, or if you want to update the quantity_available value for all the queryset objects, you can use the bulk_update or update() method of queryset. Generally, try to use update() and select_for_update() with F() expressions to update objects more effectively and handle simultaneous requests.